# compare string against tuples in list of tuples - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tuples

Attempting to create new column `Tax_Year` with appropriate tax year, formed by checking whether datetimes in `date` column are within the boundaries of the tuple elements for the individual `txYear_`...

```
salesReport  = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-07-02 09:00:00', '2017-07-03 15:00:00', '2018-04-05 15:00:00', 
                                    '2018-12-20 11:00:00', '2019-01-06 14:00:00', '2020-09-06 17:00:00'], 
                            'sales': [100, 339, 98, 1020, 630, 765]})

txYear_0304 = (dt.datetime(2003, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2004, 4, 5))
txYear_0405 = (dt.datetime(2004, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2005, 4, 5))
txYear_0506 = (dt.datetime(2005, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2006, 4, 5))
txYear_0607 = (dt.datetime(2006, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2007, 4, 5))
txYear_0708 = (dt.datetime(2007, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2008, 4, 5))
txYear_0809 = (dt.datetime(2008, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2009, 4, 5))
txYear_0910 = (dt.datetime(2009, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2010, 4, 5))
txYear_1011 = (dt.datetime(2010, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2011, 4, 5))
txYear_1112 = (dt.datetime(2011, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2012, 4, 5))
txYear_1213 = (dt.datetime(2012, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2013, 4, 5))
txYear_1314 = (dt.datetime(2013, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2014, 4, 5))
txYear_1415 = (dt.datetime(2014, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2015, 4, 5))
txYear_1516 = (dt.datetime(2015, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2016, 4, 5))
txYear_1617 = (dt.datetime(2016, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2017, 4, 5))
txYear_1718 = (dt.datetime(2017, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2018, 4, 5))
txYear_1819 = (dt.datetime(2018, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2019, 4, 5))
txYear_1920 = (dt.datetime(2019, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2020, 4, 5))
txYear_2021 = (dt.datetime(2020, 4, 6), dt.datetime(2021, 4, 5))

tax_year = [txYear_0304, txYear_0405, txYear_0506, txYear_0607, txYear_0708, txYear_0809, txYear_0910, txYear_1011, txYear_1112, 
            txYear_1213, txYear_1314, txYear_1415, txYear_1516, txYear_1617, txYear_1718, txYear_1819, txYear_1920,  txYear_2021]
```

When this condition is meet I would like to have the variable name appear in the appropriate row of the new column

**For Example**

```
                  date  sales      Tax_Year
0  2017-07-02 09:00:00    100   txYear_1617  
1  2017-07-03 15:00:00    339   txYear_1617
2  2018-04-05 15:00:00     98   txYear_1718 
3  2018-12-20 11:00:00   1020   txYear_1819
4  2019-01-06 14:00:00    630   txYear_1819
5  2020-09-06 17:00:00    765   txYear_2021
```

I have approached this problem using `np.where`....

```
salesReport['Tax_Year'] = np.where(tax_year[0] <= salesReport['date'] and tax_year[1] >= salesReport['date'], tax_year, np.nan)
```

However, I cannot resolve the error which i recieve...

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'
```

In addition, I am also unsure of how to get the variable name as at present I would be returning the actual tuple contents which is not what I want

Comment: As a tip while I continue looking at your code: you can chain comparison operators which massively helps in readability: `a < x < b` or in your case, `ty[0] <= sr <= ty[1]`.

Comment: I believe the issue is that your time stamps in your DataFrame aren't datetime objects. I don't really use Pandas though and I always thought this was automatic, but it looks like that may be happening.

Comment: Following on from your comment, I changed format...`salesReport['date'] = pd.to_datetime(salesReport['date'])` however the error is now `ValueError: Lengths must match`

Comment: Right, so I believe that's caused by the fact that you're trying to pass in a list of datetime tuples, but `np.where` expects a single boolean condition check. But what you seem to want is to check ALL tax years.

Comment: yes, I need to check all the tax years. So `np.where` is not the best path to go down for this?

Comment: Not that I can tell, but I'm at the limit of my abilities with Pandas here. I was able to come up with a method that finds the tax year for each row, but the output isn't what you want.

Comment: Given that something like tax_year[0] is a tuple, containing 2 dates: 2003-04-06 00:00:00   and   2004-04-05 00:00:00     doesn't it make more sense to compare to each of those actual dates? (as in >= tax_year[0][0]     and also     <= tax_year[0][1]  )

Comment: @blorgon maybe I can adapt what you have come up with so far...

Comment: @S_alj do you mean like this? ....`np.where(salesReport['date'] >= tax_year[0][0] and salesReport['date'] <= tax_year[0][1] , tax_year, np.nan)`

Comment: Yes, with tax_year[x][0] and tax_year[x][1] actually giving you the fiscal year edges, the datetime objects you had defined before. But it looks like you'll be comparing datetime objects, to the hardcoded date strings from the dictionary. Maybe you should parse the date strings into datetime objects, for those comparisons to actually work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer:

I'm not proficient in Pandas. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a nicer way to do this.

I've converted the `tax_years` list of tuples into a dictionary, and defined a standalone function to get the tax year of a given datetime object. I'm not actually 100% what time of day the tax year ends/begins, so the comparison is only on MM-DD-YY and removes the time from the timestamps that exist in the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

tax_years = {
    (datetime.datetime(2003, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2004, 4, 5)): "TY0304",
    (datetime.datetime(2004, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2005, 4, 5)): "TY0405",
    (datetime.datetime(2005, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 5)): "TY0506",
    (datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2007, 4, 5)): "TY0607",
    (datetime.datetime(2007, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 5)): "TY0708",
    (datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 5)): "TY0809",
    (datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 5)): "TY0910",
    (datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 5)): "TY1011",
    (datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 5)): "TY1112",
    (datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 5)): "TY1213",
    (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 5)): "TY1314",
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 5)): "TY1415",
    (datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 5)): "TY1516",
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 5)): "TY1617",
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5)): "TY1718",
    (datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5)): "TY1819",
    (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 5)): "TY1920",
    (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6), datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 5)): "TY2021"
}

salesReport  = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-07-02 09:00:00',
                                      '2017-07-03 15:00:00',
                                      '2018-04-05 15:00:00',
                                      '2018-12-20 11:00:00',
                                      '2019-01-06 14:00:00',
                                      '2020-09-06 17:00:00'], 
                            'sales': [100, 339, 98, 1020, 630, 765]})

salesReport["date"] = pd.to_datetime(salesReport["date"])


def get_tax_year(date):
    for (start, end), tax_year in tax_years.items():
        if start.date() <= date.date() <= end.date():
            return tax_year
    return "null"


salesReport["tax_year"] = [get_tax_year(date) for date in salesReport["date"]]
print(salesReport)
```

And the output:

```
                 date  sales tax_year
0 2017-07-02 09:00:00    100   TY1718
1 2017-07-03 15:00:00    339   TY1718
2 2018-04-05 15:00:00     98   TY1718
3 2018-12-20 11:00:00   1020   TY1819
4 2019-01-06 14:00:00    630   TY1819
5 2020-09-06 17:00:00    765   TY2021
```

Comment: Again, I'm WAY outside my comfort zone right now: I rarely use Pandas. I imagine there's probably a nice solution to this, but I don't know it right now. I'll continue to research since I should learn Pandas anyway. I'll update my post as I make progress.

Comment: Your efforts have been much appreciated and has given me some food for thought. Thank you

Comment: you're a star!! the end product was spot on!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm sure there's a better way using Pandas, but in the end this wound up pretty simple with an essentially pure Python approach.